# Meteor server method returns undefined in callback

Tags: javascript, meteor, callback, meteor-methods

How can I get my server methods response in client ?
When I call a server method and do a console.log on response, it gives me "undefined" on the client, but on the terminal, it returns the value as expected.

My meteor version is Meteor 1.3.2.4

Method on server

```
Meteor.methods({
    TestMethodOnProd : (arg) => {
        console.log("In Prod ", arg)
        return Meteor.userId()
    }
})
```

Calling method on client.

```
Meteor.call("TestMethodOnProd","Some text on prod",(err,res)=> {
    console.log("Err ",err)
    console.log("Res ",res)
})
```

Console.log on Client (Browser) returns

```
Err  undefined
Res  undefined
```

Console.log in the Terminal returns

```
Err  undefined
Res  <user_id_here>
```

Comment: can you make a repo for it on github? I tried doing the exact same thing and it worked perfectly fine. Did you install both `accounts-password` and `accounts-ui` ?

Take a look at this: https://github.com/ickyrr/testing-only.git

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the client:

```
Meteor.call("TestMethodOnProd","Some text on prod",(err,res)=> {
   !err ? console.log(res) : console.log(err);
})
```